# call react component in loop based on onclick button function which sets the state to true once button is clicked

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new in react, i am trying to get component based on if button is clicked and once the component is returned to Ui, i want to change button state back to original(false),so if i click on that button again i should get again new component below to the previous one,and this should just go on..,
in below code i am able to get this just one time.

```
const Command = () => {
  const [buttonState, setButtonState] = useState(false);

  const AndOrHandler = () => {
    if (buttonState) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Grid container>
            <SomeComponent />
          </Grid>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  };


  return (
    <Fragment>
      <FormControl>
        <SomeComponent />
        <AndOrHandler />
        <Button onClick={() => setButtonState(true)} variant="contained" color="primary">Add Condition</Button>
      </FormControl>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Command;
```

Comment: Are you simply wanting to toggle the `buttonState` state value to toggle the rendering of `AndOrHandler`? Or are you trying to add new elements to the UI upon each button click? The description of issue is a little vague in this regard. What is your expected behavior and try to be as clear and concise as possible.

Comment: yes, I am trying to add new elements to the UI upon each button click

Comment: Can you please update your code with the looping logic? Or is that what you want us to write for you? What have you tried?

Comment: That is the part which i am not able to figure out, how to add loop here and render component on that... i was trying with, do while, but did not got satisfactory results..

Comment: Yeah, the switching of your mindset from imperative to declarative coding is a bit of a stumbling block for many, myself included. Go with Viet's solution but I do strongly suggest using functional state updates when the next state *depends* on the current state. If you get into that habit now when you're learning you can more easily avoid an entire class of react state bugs. Good luck, mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want continue adding component, i suggest have state components:

```
const Command = () => {
    const component =  <div>
        <Grid container>
            <SomeComponent />
        </Grid>
    </div>;
    
    const [components, setComponents] = useState([]);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <FormControl>
                <SomeComponent />
                {components.map(component => component)}
                <Button onClick={() => setComponents([...components, component])} variant="contained" color="primary">Add Condition</Button>
            </FormControl>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default Command;
```

Comment: not really, I want loop like functionality, on button click i should get new new component below to previous component, your suggestion will just hide and show my current component.

Comment: The idiomatic way to toggle a boolean react state value is to use a functional update, i.e. `setButtonState(state => !state)`, BTW.

Comment: Again, the idiomatic way to enqueue state updates that *depend* on existing state is to use a functional state update, `setComponents(components => [...components, component])`.